# Coldfusion 8 refresh table/page based on cfquery.recordcount changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have a table on a page that should refresh every time a database has a record added to it (SQL Server 2005).  The page that should be refreshing is called status.cfm, the jquery src (script) tag and jquery code are encapsulated in the  tags and the jquery code is 'supposed' to fire a separate CF page called chknew.cfm (in the same dir).  Should I be separating the JS/JQ into its own file?  I'm admittedly new to using jQuery.  I based my present (non-working) solution off this question-asker's solution, dropping references to the DataTables library:

[Is there a way to 'listen' for a database event and update a page in real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471879/is-there-a-way-to-listen-for-a-database-event-and-update-a-page-in-real-time)

Here is my non-working code:

status.cfm: (calling page?)

```
<html><head><title>Status List</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  var originalNoRecs=0;
  var setChecker=setInterval(chkForNewRec,5000); //5 sec intervals

  function chkForNewRec(){
    var postData={
      noOfRecs:originalNoRecs
  };

    var ajaxResponse=$.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"./chknew.cfm",
      contentType:"application/json",
      data:JSON.stringify(postData)
    })

    ajaxResponse.then(
      function(apiResponse){
        var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(apiResponse);

        if(obj.isUpdateAvail=="Yes")
        {
          document.location.reload(true);
          alert('New Line Added!');
        }
      });
    }

 </script>
</head>
```

...followed by the code that marks up the table with the relevant data from the database.  I left the alert line in the JS so that I have a way of testing if the code is firing, which it is not.  Here is chknew.cfm (in same directory):

chknew.cfm: (handler?)

```
<cfset requestbody=tostring(gethttprequestdata().content)/>

<cfif isjson(requestbody)>

<cfset deserializedresult=deserializejson(requestbody)>
<cfset noOfRecs=deserializedresult.originalNoRecs>

<cfquery name="qCount" datasource="mydsn">SELECT COUNT(kid) AS total FROM kiosk</cfquery>

<cfif qCount.total NEQ variables.originalNoRecs>
    {"isUpdateAvail":"Yes","recordcount":<cfoutput>#qCount.total#</cfoutput>}
<cfelse>
    {"isUpdateAvail":"No"}
</cfif>

</cfif>
```

I've also tried using Firefox Dev Tools>Debugger to try and step through the JS/JQ but to no avail, it just loads the entire JavaScript block at once without going through line-by-line, I may have it set up wrong.  I'm fairly proficient at CF but have only dabbled in JS and have no experience w/ jQuery, but did quite a few web searches as to why this code isn't working, no joy on any of those.

It wouldn't surprise me if it's something obvious, I've tried a few modifications, also all to no avail.  If anyone can help me out here I'd be very grateful, I've got a manager who is not understanding why this won't "just work" and I'm perplexed as well.  My background is in network administration so this is a little outside my comfort zone.  Thank you all in advance for your responses and insight into this problem.

EDIT: I used Venkman in FF but it seems to keep crashing on me.  As far as I can tell, it's stalling at the "Var ajaxResponse=$.ajax({..." line.  I have accompanying screencaps of the various steps:

[image: Venkman output, in order left to right, top to bottom.]

So perhaps something is wrong w/ my jQuery install/version?  Do I need to actually put the jQuery file on my web root?  I was under the impression that including the

Comment: *"Should I be separating the JS/JQ into it's own file"* generally yes, but that shouldn't make your code work/not work

Comment: Have you completely debugged the coldfusion side of this? is CF receiving the json string you expect it to? is it outputting the jsonstring you expect it to?

Comment: Which part is "not working"? Is the AJAX call firing? Is CF receiving the call? Is CF returning what you expect?

Comment: @Kevin B: To be honest, I'm not too familiar w/ JSON either.  As I understand it, it's a segue between Javascript and other server-side languages such as CF/PHP...I suppose I could mock-up a serializejson page w/ chknew.cfm handling that info and report back here.  Really I'm only interested in passing the recordcount of the cfquery back to the calling page. Miguel-F: I'm expecting that when I go into SSMS and manually add a record in dbo.kiosk, I should get a refresh and alert box on status.cfm in my browser, but no such luck in practice.  Not sure how to tell if AJAX call is firing :(

Comment: Check my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6472690/11047 Depending on what browser you're using, it should have built-in developer tools to show you the ajax calls, the data being sent and the data returned. JSON is just a data format: http://www.json.org/

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo : Seems to be a great resource for testing/debugging, but I can't get it to work.  I'm using the Java version because our webserver doesn't run PHP, Ruby, nor node.js.  I have the client vers. installed on my workstation (WXP) and server vers. on my webserver, and have tried running both, then navigating to ws://<webserver ip address>:8787/jWebSocket/jWebSocket (in the URL field on the server vers.) but no joy.  I opened the LAN to LAN ports 8787, 9797, and 843 (flash is installed).  Is it the consensus of the commenters that the code above *should* work? Thank you for the help!