# Converting a coldfusion variable to be read in Ajax statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have this code written. Basically it checks the Database every 2 seconds to see if there have been changes made. If there hasn't been changes made a variable (CheckMessageCount) passes back with a value of 0 and nothing happens. If a change was made and CheckMessageCount passes back with a value of 1, the div reloads the messages on the screen.

What I'm not sure is how I pass CheckMessageCount from the cfm page back into the jquery/ajax so the if/else statement can be properly done. Right now it just goes to else all the time and does nothing.

I read how to do a query string, but I couldn't make it work. I also tried to do what [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471879/is-there-a-way-to-listen-for-a-database-event-and-update-a-page-in-real-time) had done, but no luck.

Here is what I have for the page with the Jquery/AJAX

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $.get("homepageresponse2.cfm", function (data) //gets the code behind the page
        { 
            $("#responsecontainer").html(data); //places the data in the budget div
        });

    var CheckMessageCount = 0;

    (function() {
        var reloadthediv = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "CheckMessageCount.cfc?method=ReloadMessageCount",
            type: "get",
            datatype: "json"
        })
            .done(function(CheckMessageCount) {
            //if checkmessagecount comes back 1, then reload
            if (CheckMessageCount == 1) {
                $( "#responsecontainer" ).load( "homepageresponse2.cfm" );
            //if checkmessagecount comes back 0, do nothing
            } else {
                //do nothing
                console.log('nothing done')
            } 
        });
    };

    reloadthediv();

    setInterval(function() {
        reloadthediv();
    }, 2000);
    })();
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="responsecontainer" class="responsecontainercss"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is what I have for CheckMessageCount.cfc

```
    <cfcomponent displayname="Checks The Message RecordCount to reload" hint="This is the CFC for Checks The Message RecordCount to reload"> 
    <!--- This function gets all user status data for the proper session.id if it exists ---> 
        <cffunction name="ReloadMessageCount" returntype="any" returnformat="json" hint="Gets message count"> 

        <cfquery name="CheckMessages" datasource="hippogriff" debug="No">
        SELECT  COUNT(HomePageMessage_ID) AS TheMessageCount
        FROM    HomePageMessage
        </cfquery>

        <!--- code here for the messagecount --->

        <!--- once it does, let's do this --->
        <cfif CheckMessages.TheMessageCount GT messagecount>
            <cfset CheckMessageCount=1> 
            <cfset messagecount=#CheckMessages.TheMessageCount#>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset CheckMessageCount=0> 
        </cfif> 

        <cfreturn CheckMessageCount> 
    </cffunction> 
</cfcomponent>
```

This is about as far as my knowledge goes. I tried the ColdFusion serializeJSON and couldn't get anything. I know there is websockets now, but our hosting company "doesn't support them on the server", and its really out of my reach coding. I am surprised I made it this far with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Only reason I know it semi works because I put the reload statement in the else part of the JS and it reloads the div.

Comment: I also suggest a cfc but with this approach, you are not outputting the value anywhere - you are simply setting it.  That's why nothing is being sent back to jquery.

Comment: Also, what is the source and purpose of the `messagecount` variable in the CFIF? If it is supposed to be some sort of parameter passed to the script, it must be included in the ajax call.

Comment: Dan, I updated the code to include the cfc and updated the JS because I think I had some stuff in there that wasn't needed. Leigh, the message count gets set in the cfc, I didn't include the code because it works and makes the if statement work. 

Any idea why the javascript can't recognize that the cfc passes back either a 0 or 1?

Comment: @Adam - *the message count gets set in the cfc* Okay.  Just making sure it was not something that is supposed to be passed *into* the cfc .. because the ajax call is not doing that.  Ignoring possible improvements for the moment, the $.ajax call above worked for me with `<cffunction access="remote" ....>` (as Chris mentioned). Use your browser's javascript tools to see what is happening with the ajax request and response.

Comment: Thanks Liegh, I will update the code and see what is going on.

Comment: I made the changes you all suggested and I was able to get it working. I was having trouble with the if else, but I put a $.trim in there and everything works great now. Thanks!!

Comment: Leigh, what would be some better improvements to this other than doing web sockets? This is considered long polling right? This is my very first attempt at it (I know I'm late to the party), so anything to help improve the code would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be best if you use a CFC, but in your example do this right before

```
<cfcontent type="application/json">#checkMessageCount#</cfoutput>
```

This will return a single value with the JSON MIME type. You could do serializeJSON, but there's nothing really to serialize.

cfcontent will remove all the spacing since the reset attribute defaults to 0.

Also you need to change "CheckMessageCount" to "returnresult" in your js.

Keep in mind your solution isn't really scalable and will end up bogging down your system with any decent traffic.

Be sure debugging is off for this CFM page that brings back the JSON, otherwise it'll break.

Comment: Would it change anything in the cfc? I have one done basically with the same thing and the return is <cfreturn CheckMessageCount>

Comment: Using a CFC gives you more structure to your code. You wouldn't output the var, but rather return it as you mentioned. More of a preference really.

Comment: Chris, I updated the cf and js code. I realized I might have had some wrong ajax stuff in there, could you please take another look at it? I am still not being able to get the javascript to register if the return comes back as 1.

Comment: You have to add the access="remote" attribute to the function element. A big help would be to use the browser development tools so you can see what's being passed back to it.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will update the code and see what is going on.

Comment: Chris, I got it all working. What is a better scalable way to do this?

Comment: It all really depends upon what you are doing. Outside of websockets I would look at doing event driven checks. So when a user interacts with the page in some way, do your check then.