# Restful Server Response triggered Via Client

Tags: java, android, mysql, spring, rest

This question might sound a bit abstract,answered (but did my search didn't stumble on a convenient answer) or not specific at all ,but I will try to provide as much information as I can.

I am building a mobile application which will gather and send sensory data to a remote server. The remote server will collect all these data in a mySQL database and make computations (not the mysql database ,another process/program) . What I wanna know is :

After some updates in the database , is it doable to send a response from a RESTful Server to a certain client (the one who like did the last update probably) ,using something like "a background thread"? Or this should be done via socket connection through server-client response?

Some remarks:

I am using javaEE, Spring MVC with hibernate and tomcat (cause I am familiar with the environment though in a more asynchronous manner).

I thought this would be a convenient way because the SQL schema is not much complicated and security and authentication issues are not needed (it's a prototype).

Also there is a front-end webpage that will have to visualize these data, so such a back-end system would look like a good option for getting the job done fast.

Lastly I saw this solution :

[Is there a way to 'listen' for a database event and update a page in real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471879/is-there-a-way-to-listen-for-a-database-event-and-update-a-page-in-real-time)

My issue is that besides the page I wanna update the client's side with messages from the RESTful server.

If all these above are unecessary and a more simple client-server application will prove better and less complex please be welcome to inform me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should upload your data to a resource on the server (e.g. `POST /widgets` and the server should immediately return with a `201 Created` or (if creation is too slow and needs to happen later) `202 Accepted` status. There are several approaches after that happens, each has their merits:

- Polling - The server's response includes a location field which the client can then proceed to poll until a change happens (e.g. check for an update every second). This is the easiest approach and quite efficient if you use HTTP caching effectively and the average number of checks is relatively low.
- Push notification - Server sends a push notification when the change happens, report's generated, etc. Obviously this requires you to store the client's details and their notification requirements. This is probably the cleanest approach and also easy to scale. In the case of Android (also iOS) you have free push notifications available via Google Cloud Messaging.
- Set up a persistent connection between client and server, e.g. using a Websocket or low-level TCP connection. This should yield the fastest response times, but will probably be a drain on phone battery, harder to scale on the server, and more complex to code.