# How to update view on computer when the data has been added from another computer or phone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Actually in my WebSite i have an ajax call where i get from ASPX some data from the MySQL database.

From that data i build a chart by using Chart.JS and i would be able to update that chart when there was added a new data to the DataBase from ANOTHER device.

The website is a webservice so the website can be opened on a computer then from my phone i can load the same page and add some new items to the DataBase, the view on the phone has been updated but not on the computer so how can i update the view even on the computer?

Let's assume i have a form in my website and a list, the website is opened on my computer and my phone, after compiling the form from the phone and submitting it in the list will compare the new item and i would that even on the computer that item will compare without refreshing the page.

Actually here is my ajax call for creating the chart, is it possible to make something like a poll of it to refresh if there is new data?

```
function loadReports(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/getReports",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ data: data }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            data = r.d;
            if (data != '[]') {
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                var dataObject = {
                    labels: data.map(ora => ora.ORARIO),
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Coperti',
                        backgroundColor: gradient,
                        hoverBackgroundColor: gradient,
                        data: data.map(cop => cop.COPERTI)
                    }]          
                };
                chart.data = dataObject;
                chart.update();
            } else {
                var dataObject = {
                    labels: [],
                    datasets: []
                }
                chart.data = dataObject;
                chart.update();
            }

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.responseText);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to 'listen' for a database event and update a page in real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471879/is-there-a-way-to-listen-for-a-database-event-and-update-a-page-in-real-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like `setInterval` to request data from the server at regular intervals, to request every 5 seconds you could do something like:

```
setInterval(() => loadReports(data), 5000)
```

Alternatively, you could look at using websockets. This is basically where your backend can tell the client that something has changed and it should update (or just send the data anyway). You can read a nice introduction to websockets at https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-websockets (it's a few years old but still a good introduction)

Comment: Actually websocket will be a nice solution but for a primitive solution i'd gonna use the setInterval :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) for broadcasting your data from server side to client side. It uses websocket technology. If a specific page is updated then data is sent to pusher server and can catch that data from your client side( where you are showing your chart) using javascript.

If you use ajax it would drain your bandwidth much more than using pusher.

You can choose Redis, firebase, pubnub if you don't like pusher.